# Как через Tag получить доступ к определенному номеру `ComboBox` на форме?

Tags: delphi

Как через `Tag` получить доступ к определенному номеру `ComboBox` на форме? Как через `property` записать, например, в класс какое-то новое значение?

Comment: задачу точнее, пожалуйста

Comment: У каждого компонента свойство Tag по умолчанию равно нулю. Так что, если нужно к Tag обращаться в зависимости от номера компонента, то нужно его задать заранее (у каждого требуемого компонента) на этапе рисования формы. Я бы воспользовался этим свойством (Tag), если бы создавал массив компонентов (ComboBox'ов и др.).

Answer (score 1):

for i:=0 to form1.components.count-1 do

begin

if form1.components[i].tag=<твой таг> then

<делаем с компонентом то, что нужно, например вставляем новый итем в комбобокс>

(form1.components[i] as TCombobox).Items.Add('new item');

end;